# How to execute command in Windows Service?

Tags: c#, windows-services, cmd

I want to execute "start [Filename].txt" at fixed interval.
So I decide to create windows service.
But I am not getting idea to execute this command through windows service.
Other logic i have implemented. Just remaining is execute command.

Comment: Is "start" the name of an executable and [Filename].txt an argument you are passing to it. I think the sugested `Process.Start("filename.txt")` will probably open filename.txt in a text editor on a none existent desktop

Comment: Ben, I believe you are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Process.Start will not accomplish your likely goal if in a Windows Service.  It may launch the process....into session 0, so you will never see it.  To launch a process from a service that the user can interact with, you will need to create the process in the user session, a pretty non-trivial thing to do from inside a windows service (but certainly possible).  You might be best to look at a Windows Scheduled Task as @jglouie suggested.

Comment: Can you explain me How can I launch it into user session. So I can see that.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can simply use:

```
Process.Start("filename.txt");
```

If you need to start that file and wait for it to close or some other particular action, take a look at [Process Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx).

Comment: I will see. Thanks for replay

Answer (score 2):

`Process.Start("filename.txt")` will work as @Marco answered

I'm wondering if you could get away with a [Windows Scheduled Task](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/schedule-a-task) instead of a service.

Is that all your service does?

Comment: Thank you for replay. I didn't know about it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Create a PowerShell script and have it executed on schedule by task scheduler...